# How to replace a dropdown menu with a new list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

**Existing HTML Code**

```
<select id="city_name" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Option3</option>
      <option>Option4</option>
      <option>Option5</option>
</select>
```

**Should be changed to**

```
<select id="city_name" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
      <option>New Option 1</option>
      <option>New Option 2</option>
</select>
```

I am using below code but its not working properly

```
document.getElementById("city_name").innerHTML = document.getElementById("city_name").innerHTML.replace(/<([^>]+?)([^>]*?)>(.*?)<\/\1>/ig,'<select id=\"city_name\" name=\"user[city]\" class=\"form-control\"><option>Testing<\/option><\/select>');
```

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("city_name").innerHTML = '<option>New Option 1</option> <option>New Option 2</option> ';
```

or you can write this:

```
$("#city_name").html('<option>New Option 1</option> <option>New Option 2</option>');
```

Comment: *"or you can write this:"* What is this `$`?

Comment: Thank you All, I tried this one it worked perfectly. Thank You Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just like that?

```
document.getElementById("city_name").innerHTML =
document.getElementById("city_name").innerHTML
  .replace(new RegExp('>Option', 'g'), '>New Option ');
```

Comment: That seems to make assumptions about how `innerHTML` serializes the DOM structure.

Comment: In the end, the select will have five options though, not just two.

Comment: sorry, missed right answer. task was more simple then I thought :) np

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#changelist").on('click', function(e) {
  $("#city_name").html("<option>New Option 1</option><option>New Option 2</option>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="city_name" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
  <option>Option5</option>
</select>
<button id='changelist'>
  Click me!
</button>
```

Comment: What is this `$`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use different ids, so your javascript will understand which id to select and which one to replace:

```
<select id="id_baseCityName" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Option3</option>
      <option>Option4</option>
      <option>Option5</option>
</select>

<select id="id_tobeReplacedCityName" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
      <option>New Option 1</option>
      <option>New Option 2</option>
</select>


document.getElementById("id_baseCityName").innerHTML = document.getElementById("id_tobeReplacedCityName").innerHTML;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ducfilan/n73u56go/

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the innerHTML with `option`

```js
function change(){
document.getElementById("city_name").innerHTML ='<option>New Option 1</option><option>New Option 2</option>';
  }
```

```html
<select id="city_name" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Option3</option>
      <option>Option4</option>
      <option>Option5</option>
</select>
<button onclick="change()">change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`HTMLSelectElement#remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove) to remove existing options and [`HTMLSelectElement#add`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add) to add new options:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("city_name");

// Remove all existing options
while (select.length > 0) {
  select.remove(0);
}

// Set new options
var newValue = [
  'New Option 1',
  'New Option 2',
];
newValue.forEach(function(value) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = value;
  select.add(option);
});
```

```html
<select id="city_name" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Option3</option>
  <option>Option4</option>
  <option>Option5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const $select = document.querySelector('#city_name');

// Remove existing options
while( $select.hasChildNodes() ){
  $select.removeChild( $select.childNodes[0] );
}

$select.appendChild(newOptionElem('New Option 1'));
$select.appendChild(newOptionElem('New Option 2'));

function newOptionElem(txt){
  let $elem = document.createElement('option'),
      textNode = document.createTextNode(txt);
  
  $elem.appendChild(textNode);
  return $elem;
}
```

```html
<select id="city_name" name="user[city]" class="form-control">
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Option3</option>
      <option>Option4</option>
      <option>Option5</option>
</select>
```